# set datetimepicker input field to empty by default in ejs-datetimepicker by @syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, syncfusion

I have used datetime picker from @syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars. As of now, the datetime picker shows current date and time by default in its input field which i want to be empty by default. Is it possible to do so? Any leads would be very helpful.

Comment: i did it using datetime picker by syncfusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncfusion support here.

The **default value of our EJ2 DateTimePicker** is **Null**. So, if you have configured value property then DateTimePicker will be rendered based on the provided value else component will be rendered with empty input. We have prepared the sample to showcase this and attached it below.

**Sample Link**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-budu77-c6nwtf?file=app.component.ts

To know more about our component, please refer to the below documentation and demo link.

**UG Link**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/datetimepicker/getting-started/#running-the-application

**API Link**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/datetimepicker/#value

**Demo Link**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/datetimepicker/default